# Keep all html whitespaces in php mysql

Tags: php, whitespace

i want to know how to keep all whitespaces of a text area in php (for send to database), and then echo then back later. I want to do it like stackoverflow does, for codes, which is the best approach?

For now i using this:

```
$text = str_replace(' ', '&nbs p;', $text);
```

It keeps the `' '` whitespaces but i won't have tested it with `mysql_real_escape` and other "inject prevent" methods together.

For better understanding, i want to echo later from db something like:

```
 function jack(){
    var x = "blablabla";
 }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1. Store the data as is 2. rightclick the code block of you question and choose "inspect element" 3. ? 4. profit!

Comment: But if i use mysql_real_escape and do a line break with 5 white spaces on second line, it will echo just one, or none. How the proper way to echo it back using the white space char code? Or should i save then on db already using the whitespace code?

Comment: Read my comment and not just the 5 first words. The whitespace is there, but the user agent (the browser) just doesn't display it. Also stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, because they will be removed from the language soon.

Comment: You wont answer a question saying "1 2 3" it`s done. Please, if you wont want to help, let someway that want and don`t do offensive comments. What i wanted is the better approach, the safer, for code blocks.

Comment: 1. It isn't an answer, but a comment. 2. It actually answers your question. 3. ? 4. I fail to see how any of my comments where offensive?

Answer (score 1):

### Code Blocks

If you're trying to just recreate code blocks like:

```
function test($param){
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then you should be using `<pre></pre>` tags in your `html`:

```
<pre>
    function test($param){
        return TRUE;
    }
</pre>
```

As plain `html` will only show one space even if multiple spaces/newlines/tabs are present. Inside of `pre` tags spaces will be shown as is.

At the moment your `html` will look something like this:

```
function test($param){
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return TRUE;
}
```

Which I would suggest isn't desirable...

### Escaping

When you use `mysql_real_escape` you will convert newlines to plain text `\n` or `\r\n`. This means that your code would output something like:

```
function test($param){\n return TRUE;\n}
```

OR

```
<pre>function test($param){\n    return TRUE;\n}</pre>
```

To get around this you have to replace the `\n` or `\r\n` strings to newline characters.

Assuming that you're going to use `pre` tags:

```
echo preg_replace('#(\\\r\\\n|\\\n)#', "\n", $escapedString);
```

If you want to switch to `html` line breaks instead you'd have to switch `"\n"` to `<br />`. If this were the case you'd also want to switch out space characters   with `&nbsp;` - I suggest using the `pre` tags.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I was wondering if i can use mysql_real_escape with the pre tags and you answered that.

Answer (score 1):

try this, works excellently

```
$string = nl2br(str_replace(" ", " &nbsp;", $string));
echo "$string";
```